# Kubernetes local storageclass (kubernetes.io/no-provisioner) retain policy volume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, storage-class-specifier

Persistent volume doesn't retain existing data when pod is deleted and deployed back.

Once pod is removed, mapped persistent volume status changed to **Released**. Later when the same pod redeployed we can't use the same existing PV since it's not in **Available** state.

As suggested in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain, 
I have tried deleting **Released** PV and created the same PV where status is **Available** and it **Bound** to recreated pod but old data missing.

**How we can claim the same PV with old data when pod is deleted and created back?**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: local-storage
annotations:
storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

-------------------------------

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: app-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: role
          operator: In
          values:
          - data
```

Comment: It does not make sense, If you delete the pod, pv should not be deleted as the life cycle of both objects are independent of eachother. That's why pod can be destroyed many times without impacting the PV

Comment: When we purge the application from helm chart it removed deployed apps and respective PVC. PV is not removed but status changed to RELEASED. Again Helm install application does install PVC but same PV is not bounded due to RELEASED state instead of AVAILABLE. PVC went to PENDING state so my question is how we can make use of same PV with old data for newly created PVC

Comment: I would make sure that PVC is not deleted, as there is a cascading effect of it on PV. You can redeploy the deployment

Comment: Got it, I should apply statefulset & volumeclaimtemplate for my application to retain PVC.